# How can I git-archive remotely and from a Branch?

Tags: git

I'd like to get a tarball directly from a remote git server and from the tip of a branch for my PHP deployment script, it would simpler than keeping a useless clone on the production server.

Is that possible ?

Thanks,

Nico.

Answer (score 0):

The clone on the production server is not useless. It mitigates having to transfer all the necessary objects when you decide to deploy again. I'm not sure that it would be much simpler if you didn't need to do this.